# Audi A6 C6 3.0 TDI Revs Fluctuation and White Smoke

Tags: engine, egr, exhaust-manifold

I have a really unusual problem.

Once in a while (it doesn't do this always, it's really but really RANDOM), the car when warming up, it starts revs fluctuation and white smoke coming from exhausts.

Rev fluctuation:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/DTlg1P9vygQ

The white smoke:
https://www.youtube.com/shorts/2DQmhGgbhlQ

this is so random and I cannot even reproduce it in any way. I've been living with this symptom for more than 1 year now and cannot seem to find a solution.

**VCDS throws P0401 Exhaust Gas Recirc. Flow: insufficient Detected. and Cylinder 3 Glow Plug Circuit.**

I have:

- Tested my injectors in a tester. They told me all 6 need to be replaced (turned out to be just a scam car shop, the injectors work fine, only Injector 1 stays at -1.2 in VCDS , all the others within range. Plus more than 6 other service shops told me that if the injectors were the cause, it would do it every time you start the car, not randomly once a week. I also cleaned the injectors in the mean time.
- Two weeks ago I got P0087 Fuel Rail / System Pressure too low, I've then since changed the Fuel Pressure sensor, the error came off and car worked pretty fine for a week, then it started doing the fluctuation again yesterday morning (no low pressure error code this time)
- I cleaned EGR and Manifolds , no noticeable dirt was found on them to say that they were the issue anyways.

The car, when the revs fluctuate, it also jumps between fluctuations, and I also can hear the whole engine / injectors cranking while it is in that stage.

What happens is *in chronological order* :

- I start up the car. It starts at 850 RPM because it's cold (we're talking 10 degrees celsius, not too much cold).
- I start to drive.
  [29 out of 30 times]
- Car reaches 90 degrees fine, revs drop to 600-650RPM and car is smooth.
  [1 out of 30 times]
- When temp reaches 60-70 degrees celsius, the engine starts to work really bad, i can hear the cranking of the injectors.
- The revs start to jump (like the video above), when car is stopped, or even when I release the brakes (but no gas!), if I start to drive with above 1500 RPM it works fine.
- After a while of cranking, revs fluctuation and even white smoke coming from exhausts, car reaches 90 degrees, revs drop to 650-700RPM.
- The issue doesn't stop, now the car DOES NOT fluctuate revs on idle, but only when I press the gas so lightly at 900RPM. The gearbox shifts are really really hard at this time.

It would require a couple of KM drive and some turn off / turn ons and the issue will resolve, to only present again a week or two later.

Any ideas? I can't find anything anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If there is a problem with the #3 glow plug and it's not heating up, this could be your problem. It would only do it when the engine is completely cold. You might want to see if you can solve that issue first. The other code may not be helping either. If the EVAP circuit is allowing the system to suck raw fuel, might be causing the white smoke as well due to excess/unburnt fuel.